# Extract String with regex

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Node.js, I would like to extract multiple strings from a given string.
The string to search from looks like this:

```
Mon May 17 10:17:44 2021 SEND MESSAGE TO NETWORK (10.0.158.24:5060 [UDP]) (BUFF LEN = 308)
----------------------utf8-----------------------
SIP/2.0 100 Trying
To: "+3212345678" <sip:+3212345678@10.9.250.10;user=phone>
From: "+32456123456" <sip:+32456123456@ims.belgacom.be;user=phone>;tag=1c506737759
Call-ID: 13546624971752021101743@10.0.158.24
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.158.24:5060;branch=z9hG4bKac551823835
Content-Length: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Mon May 17 10:17:44 2021 11f7 [CCall::checkAuthentication] INVITE
Mon May 17 10:17:44 2021 [DBG: CResponse::freeAttributes] Ends
Mon May 17 10:17:44 2021 6367C [CMessage::send] sip_sendMessage (10.0.158.24:5060)
Mon May 17 10:17:44 2021 SEND MESSAGE TO NETWORK (10.0.158.24:5060 [UDP]) (BUFF LEN = 496)
----------------------utf8-----------------------
SIP/2.0 480 Temporarily not available
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, BYE, PRACK, NOTIFY, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, OPTIONS, UPDATE
User-Agent: OmniPCX Enterprise R12.4 m5.204.2.b
To: "+3212345678" <sip:+3212345678@10.9.250.10;user=phone>;tag=fa4096f6eb58184a573b7fcb86a7adff
From: "+32456123456" <sip:+32456123456@ims.belgacom.be;user=phone>;tag=1c506737759
Call-ID: 13546624971752021101743@10.0.158.24
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.158.24:5060;branch=z9hG4bKac551823835
Content-Length: 0

-------------------------------------------------
1621239464 -> Mon May 17 10:17:44 2021 6367C [CMessage::onSendSuccess]
Mon May 17 10:17:44 2021 2107 [CTransaction::onSendSuccess] CMessage 6367C send Success
Mon May 17 10:17:44 2021 15cd [CDialog::onSendSuccess]
```

I want to extract everything between '----------------------utf8-----------------------' and '-------------------------------------------------'

I tried following:

```
let matches = givenString.match(/-{22}utf8-{23}(.*?)-{49}/g).map((val) => {
    return val.replace(/-{22}utf8-{23}/g, '')
})
console.log(matches)
```

But the result is 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null'

I also tried to without counting the '-' characters

```
let matches = givenString.match(/----------------------utf8-----------------------(.*?)-------------------------------------------------/g)
```

But same result ('TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null')

Comment: I think you should add `s` flag at the end, single line. With it `.` matches new line characters.

Comment: I just tried the very same and it worked just fine.

Comment: Maybe the problem lies where you read the text into `givenString`?

Comment: I'm creating the String by reading a file

let givenString = fs.readFileSync('test2.txt').toString(), could this be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The Regexp doesn't work that way. It will not recognize the `(.*?)` part as to be accross multiple lines. For this you have to be using the `s` flag.

`let matches = givenString.match(/-{22}utf8-{23}(.*?)-{49}/gs) //...`
`-----------------------------------------------------------^`

```js
let givenString = `Mon May 17 10:17:44 2021 SEND MESSAGE TO NETWORK (10.0.158.24:5060 [UDP]) (BUFF LEN = 308)
----------------------utf8-----------------------
SIP/2.0 100 Trying
To: "+3212345678" <sip:+3212345678@10.9.250.10;user=phone>
From: "+32456123456" <sip:+32456123456@ims.belgacom.be;user=phone>;tag=1c506737759
Call-ID: 13546624971752021101743@10.0.158.24
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.158.24:5060;branch=z9hG4bKac551823835
Content-Length: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Mon May 17 10:17:44 2021 11f7 [CCall::checkAuthentication] INVITE
Mon May 17 10:17:44 2021 [DBG: CResponse::freeAttributes] Ends
Mon May 17 10:17:44 2021 6367C [CMessage::send] sip_sendMessage (10.0.158.24:5060)
Mon May 17 10:17:44 2021 SEND MESSAGE TO NETWORK (10.0.158.24:5060 [UDP]) (BUFF LEN = 496)
----------------------utf8-----------------------
SIP/2.0 480 Temporarily not available
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, BYE, PRACK, NOTIFY, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, OPTIONS, UPDATE
User-Agent: OmniPCX Enterprise R12.4 m5.204.2.b
To: "+3212345678" <sip:+3212345678@10.9.250.10;user=phone>;tag=fa4096f6eb58184a573b7fcb86a7adff
From: "+32456123456" <sip:+32456123456@ims.belgacom.be;user=phone>;tag=1c506737759
Call-ID: 13546624971752021101743@10.0.158.24
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.0.158.24:5060;branch=z9hG4bKac551823835
Content-Length: 0

-------------------------------------------------
1621239464 -> Mon May 17 10:17:44 2021 6367C [CMessage::onSendSuccess]
Mon May 17 10:17:44 2021 2107 [CTransaction::onSendSuccess] CMessage 6367C send Success
Mon May 17 10:17:44 2021 15cd [CDialog::onSendSuccess]
`

let matches = givenString.match(/-{22}utf8-{23}(.*?)-{49}/gs).map((val) => {
    return val.replace(/-{22}utf8-{23}/g, '')
})
console.log(matches)
```